# Getter returns whole function on null value

Tags: javascript, object, getter-setter

I've created a simple storage object to store a name with setters and getters. However, trying to fetch the name before it is set returns the function? I would want it to return null

```
name: function (val) {
    var value = val;

    this.__defineGetter__('value', function () {
        if (value == null) return null;
        return value;
    });

    this.__defineSetter__('value', function(val) {
        value = val;
    });
},
```

For the full code:

http://jsfiddle.net/GKC4P/2/

Comment: Because you're declaring name as a function. Then you overwrite it with a string. It's never even executing the code to define the get/set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way. You don't need getters or setters

```
var storage = {};

Object.defineProperty(storage, 'name', {
   value : null,
   writable: true

});

alert(storage.name);
storage.name = 'Bob';
alert(storage.name);
```

This will also work the same way.

Comment: Why do you need the `Object.defineProperty` bit? It should work fine without this.

Answer (score 0):

`name` is a method of your `storage` object - which when called creates a setter/getter for the `.value` property. What you want is

```
var storage = {};
var value = val;
storage.__defineGetter__('name', function () {
    if (value == null) return null;
    return value;
});
storage.__defineSetter__('name', function(val) {
    value = val;
});
```

Or with proper `Object.defineProperty` and an IEFE for making `value` local:

```
var storage = (function() {
    var value = val;
    return Object.defineProperty({}, 'name', {
        get: function () {
            if (value == null) return null;
            return value;
        },
        set: function(val) {
            value = val;
        }
   });
}());
```